# creating new tibble columns based on mapping plus user data

Tags: r, purrr, dplyr, tibble

I am trying generate new columns in a tibble from the output of a function that takes as input several existing columns of that tibble  plus user data. As a simplified example, I would want to use this function

```
addup <- function(x, y, z){x + y + z}
```

and use it to add the numbers in the existing columns in this tibble...

```
set.seed(1)
(tib <- tibble(num1 = sample(12), num2 = sample(12)))
# A tibble: 12 x 2
    num1  num2
   <int> <int>
 1     8     5
 2     6     3
 3     7     7
 4     3    11
 5     1     2
 6     2     1
 7    11     6
 8    10     9
 9     4     8
10     9    12
11     5    10
12    12     4
```

...together with user input. For instance, if a user defines the vector

```
vec <- c(3,6,4)
```

I would like to generate one new column per item in `vec`, adding the mapped values with the user input values.

The desired result in this case would look something like:

```
# A tibble: 12 x 5
    num1  num2   `3`   `6`   `4`
   <int> <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1     5     7    15    18    16
 2     8     2    13    16    14
 3     7     9    19    22    20
 4     1    11    15    18    16
 5     3     3     9    12    10
 6     9    12    24    27    25
 7     6     6    15    18    16
 8    10    10    23    26    24
 9    11     4    18    21    19
10    12     5    20    23    21
11     4     1     8    11     9
12     2     8    13    16    14
```

If I know `vec` beforehand, I could achieve this by

```
tib %>% 
  mutate("3" = map2_dbl(num1, num2, ~addup(.x, .y, 3)),
         "6" = map2_dbl(num1, num2, ~addup(.x, .y, 6)), 
         "4" = map2_dbl(num1, num2, ~addup(.x, .y, 4)))
```

but as the length of vec can vary, I do not know how to generalize this. I've found this answer [repeated mutate in tidyverse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51337624/repeated-mutate-in-tidyverse), but there the functions are repeated over the existing columns instead of using the multiple existing columns for mapping.

Any ideas?

Comment: I am not clear on the desired interface. do the existing columns need to be user specified? can there be different numbers of those too? does your equivalent of `addup` need to operate on single elements of the columns (hence map2) or does it take vectors as inputs?

Comment: the existing tibble with columns is already present and is not user-specified. The function I use is a custom plot function, that with each call uses the single values from the cols as input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This uses `lapply` to apply the function to each element of your vector then binds the result to the original data frame and adds column names.

```
# Given example
set.seed(1)
(tib <- tibble(num1 = sample(12), num2 = sample(12)))
addup <- function(x, y, z){x + y + z}
vec <- c(3,6,4)

# Add columns and bind to original data frame
foo <- cbind(tib, lapply(vec, function(x)addup(tib$num1, tib$num2, x)))

# Correct column names
colnames(foo)[(ncol(tib)+1):ncol(foo)] <- vec

# Print result
print(foo)

#    num1 num2  3  6  4
# 1     4    9 16 19 17
# 2     5    5 13 16 14
# 3     6    8 17 20 18
# 4     9   11 23 26 24
# 5     2    6 11 14 12
# 6     7    7 17 20 18
# 7    10    3 16 19 17
# 8    12    4 19 22 20
# 9     3   12 18 21 19
# 10    1    1  5  8  6
# 11   11    2 16 19 17
# 12    8   10 21 24 22
```

Comment: Similarly, you could use `Map` from base R to loop over each input - `tib[as.character(vec)] <- Map(addup, tib[1], tib[2], vec)`

Comment: this works with the addup function, but unfortunately not with the plot function I am trying to use the columns for as input. If I for instance use `lapply(vec, function(x) qplot(tib$num1, tib$num2, main = x))` then it generates 3 plots with each 12 points. What I would like is to get 3x12 plots with 1 point (x and y from the num cols) and the title according to the vec names.

Comment: @MartijnVanAttekum - I think that's quite different from the initial query - something like `Map(function(x,y,z) qplot(x,y,main=z), tib$num1, tib$num2, rep(vec,each=nrow(tib)) )` in base R should do it though if I'm interpreting correctly.

Answer (score 3):

Since we don't have to have the function or the colnames as arguments, this is relatively simple. You just need to iterate over `vec` with a function that returns the summed column, and then combine with the original table. If you have an `addup` function that accepts vector inputs then you can skip the whole `map2` part; in fact this one does but I don't know if your real function does.

```r
library(tidyverse)
vec <- c(3,6,4)
set.seed(1)
tib <- tibble(num1 = sample(12), num2 = sample(12))

addup <- function(c1, c2, z) {c1 + c2 + z}
addup_vec <- function(df, vec) {
  new_cols <- map_dfc(
    .x = vec,
    .f = function(v) {
      map2_dbl(
        .x = df[["num1"]],
        .y = df[["num2"]],
        .f = ~ addup(.x, .y, v)
      )
    }
  )
  colnames(new_cols) <- vec
  bind_cols(df, new_cols)
}

tib %>%
  addup_vec(vec)
#> # A tibble: 12 x 5
#>     num1  num2   `3`   `6`   `4`
#>    <int> <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#>  1     4     9    16    19    17
#>  2     5     5    13    16    14
#>  3     6     8    17    20    18
#>  4     9    11    23    26    24
#>  5     2     6    11    14    12
#>  6     7     7    17    20    18
#>  7    10     3    16    19    17
#>  8    12     4    19    22    20
#>  9     3    12    18    21    19
#> 10     1     1     5     8     6
#> 11    11     2    16    19    17
#> 12     8    10    21    24    22
```

Created on 2019-01-16 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).